# C# httpclient request size/bandwidth

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

Basically I'm sending a http post request using HttpClient, but the total response of the kb is roughly 60kb, however I only need to read the response url to determine the outcome, is there anyway I can just read response url rather than the entire data?

Example of the code I'm currently using

```
            string URI = "example.com";
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.PostAsync(URI);

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            string source = content.ToString();

            return source;
```

What this does is return the body content of " Example.com " but I later realised I wouldn't need to read the body content for a string to determine the outcome, but just simply get the response urls.

I assume this would decrease the size of the request drastically if I'm able to receive the response url of the post request without receiving the body content or other content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `HttpCompletionOption` with proper overload of [`SendAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) method and rewrite your code like

```cs
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
var response = await _client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

Comment: Thanks you put me on the right tracks, appreciate your help :)